# How to write unittests for interactive matplotlib figures?

Tags: python, unit-testing, matplotlib

I want to write unittest for interactive matplotlib plots. My problem is that I couldn't find a good way of simulating key press or mouse button press events. I know about pyautogui, but then I'd have to care about the position of the matplotlib window on the screen (also, for example on TravisCI I doubt it would work properly without configuring it). I've tried looking into Matplotlib's unittests, but I couldn't find anything useful yet. The best solution would be triggering an event inside the code without involving the GUI part, but so far I couldn't solve it.

The easiest example I've managed to come up with is below. You can mark points on the plot using the `i` key. The function here I want to test is `on_press`.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class PointRecorder:
    def __init__(self, x, y):

        plt.ion()

        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.cid = self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", self.on_press)

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.x_points, self.y_points = [2], [0.5]

        plt.plot(self.x, self.y, "r")
        self.pts, = plt.plot(self.x_points, self.y_points, "ko", markersize=6, zorder=99)

        plt.show(block=True)

    def on_press(self, event):
        ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata
        if event.inaxes is None:
            return
        if event.key == 'i':
            self.x_points.append(ix)
            self.y_points.append(iy)
            self.pts.set_data(self.x_points, self.y_points)
        if self.pts.stale:
            self.figure.canvas.draw_idle()


    def get_data(self):
        return self.pts.get_data()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = np.linspace(0, 6, 100)
    y = np.sin(x)

    graph = PointRecorder(x, y)

    print(*graph.get_data())
```

Can you suggest a way how this kind of functionality should be tested properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, the solution is the following: First define a blank event.

```py
from unittest import mock

def mock_event(xdata, ydata, button, key, fig, canvas, inaxes=True):

    event = mock.Mock()
    event.button = button
    event.key = key
    event.xdata, event.ydata = xdata, ydata
    event.inaxes = inaxes
    event.fig = fig
    event.canvas = canvas
    event.guiEvent = None
    event.name = 'MockEvent'

    return event
```

Then initialize the `PointRecorder` class above. After that, define a `mock_event` which suits the `PointRecorder.on_press` method properly. Also `patch` `plt.show` to avoid blocking execution.

```py
@mock.patch("matplotlib.pyplot.show")
def test_insert(mock_show):
    x, y = np.arange(100), np.arange(100)
    
    obj = PointRecorder(x, y)
    mck = mock_event(xdata=50, ydata=40, button="i", key="i", fig=obj.figure, canvas=obj.figure.canvas, inaxes=True)
    obj.on_clicked(event=mck)
    a, b = obj.get_data()
    np.testing.assert_array_equal(a, np.array([2, 50])) # 2 was originally in the __init__
    np.testing.assert_array_equal(b, np.array([0.5, 40])) # 0.5 was originally in the __init__
    mock_show.assert_called()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on unit testing, but my guess is that you need to instantiate an Event object (in the case of key_press_event, it should be a [KeyEvent](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.KeyEvent)) and call `graph.on_press(event)` from your testing code